# Fetching navigation menu items inside a liferay fragment

Tags: fragment, liferay

I am working on a custom fragment in liferay 7.4 and I would like to fetch the navigation menu items in the fragment to use them as list items in my html component. The problem is, I used the headless api and consumed it using basic authentication and it returned the navigation menu items just fine but the approach is not feasible. Is there another way to do in liferay and fetch the navigation menu items by using a service or so in liferay not normal js fetch.

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So, for each page request, you want to introduce one or more additional requests to fetch the navigation (that you can already get server-side, e.g. through the menu display widget and other means). A great way to double the load on your server, for no apparent gain - I'd call this freemarker-abuse.

Instead, utilize the existing "navigation menus" or "menu display" options and you're done - no authentication mockery, no extra request. Just standard CMS features (not even programming).

If you *really* want, you can write your own custom template for menu display. Start with the existing "Application Display Templates" in global scope and tweak them as you like.